# flutter_screenutil - text size is different on emulator vs real phone

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_screenutil so that the design on my emulator is the same as on my real device.  However, no matter what I do the text sizes, line height and container dimensions on my real device are never the same as on my emulator.  Here is just one example of the text not being correct.

[image]

Here is my code...

```
ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(390, 844),  // iPhone 12 dimensions
  minTextAdapt: true,
  splitScreenMode: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context, widget) => OverlaySupport(
     child: MaterialApp(
       ...
     )
   )
 )

  ...

  Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
     Text(
       title, 
       style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
          fontSize: 15.sp,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
       ),
       Text(
        subtitle,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey.shade500,
          fontSize: 13.sp,
      ),
    ),
  ]
  ...
 )
```

The difference between my emulator and my Android devices is even more pronounced.  Any idea what I can do to make this a more perfect match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 : I think the problem encountered here is not the font size, you can dynamically adjust the height and width of the container in which you write the text. Example: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / width`

Solution 2 : You can keep it stable on different screens by using the font sizes in the material design concept.
`Text("data", style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,),`